# Complex number to the high power

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

How do I solve this equation:

$$\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}i\right)^{95}$$

I'm guessing that I have to split up the 95 into smaller exponents but I have no idea if this is right. Can someone please explain the process thoroughly. Thanks.

Comment: What equation? What's the unknown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is polar coordinates.

Note that $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i=e^{\frac{-3\pi i}{8}}$. So your answer is $(e^{\frac{-3\pi i}{8}})^{95}=e^{\frac{-3\cdot 95\pi i}{8}}=e^{\frac{-285\pi i}{8}}=e^{\frac{3\pi i}{8}}=\boxed{\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i}$.

Comment: $e^{\frac{-3\pi i}{8}}$ or $e^{\frac{-3\pi i}{4}}$ ?

Comment: uh... :3 oops but too late rn :\

Answer (score 1):

Squaring twice gives:

$$
z = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)
$$

$$
\require{cancel}
z^2 = \frac{1}{2}(\cancel{1}+2i+\cancel{i^2}) = i 
$$

$$
z^4 = -1
$$

Therefore:

$$
z^{95} = z^{4\cdot 23 + 3} = (z^4)^{23}\,z^3 = (-1)^{23}\,z^3 = - z\,z^2 = \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i) = \cdots
$$